# create a floating widget that sticks on top or at a certain height when you scroll

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to make a widget sticky when it hits the top and even at a certain height from the top using Flutter.
I need that search field to stuck when it reach the top, never seen it any where apart from the web so i don't know how to create the effect.

[image]

Comment: guys, any help??